# Tap to exchange data between device A and device B

Tags: android, ios

We want to develop application which used to share important data in secure way. Idea is:

Data to be exchanged between phone A and phone B (and vice versa) when users “Tap” the phones together. The date, time and location of this action is to be recorded.
This should work anywhere (in buildings or in rural areas where there is no mobile signal coverage), and work cross platform (iOS, Android, Windows).

we want to know is it possible to develop such application ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can 'bump' phones and send over Bluetooth. You would use the accelerometer of the phones to detect the 'bump' part. The date, time and location you can pull straight from the devices (given you have GPS permission).

It would be a lot of work to develop right, especially across multiple platforms, and I believe an app like that already exists, for sharing contact information.

Also for future reference, you're probably getting down-votes because you're not asking specifically about code. Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks @Johnny Rockex  for sharing yor experience. I will follow your advice.